# Cardinality summation

Tags: summation

How do I prove that, for set $X$,

$$\sum_{S\subseteq X, S\neq \emptyset}\frac{(-1)^{|S|}}{|X|+|S|} = \frac{|X|!(|X|-1)!}{(2|X|)!}$$

I have been around this exercise all day and would much appreciate your help.

Comment: What is SCX? Also note that [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) can help you format your question is more reader-friendly way.

Comment: @Marta, I've done my best typesetting your question; please let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: yes, thank you,that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: That seems odd, since if $|X|=1$, the LHS is $\frac{-1}{2}$ while the RHS is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: What does this mean for an infinite $X$? What is $\dfrac{(-1)^{\aleph_0}}{\aleph_2}$?

Comment: I have no idea. This is a recurrence exercise, but this is all the information I got.

Comment: The formula holds for $|X|=1,2$ if you add $\emptyset$ to the summation of the lhs. Otherwise it is false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us denote $n = |X|$. Then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{S\subset X} \frac{(-1)^{|S|}}{|X|+|S|}
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{n+k}
 = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{k} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n+k-1} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{k} x^{n+k-1} \, dx
 = \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} (1 - x)^{n} \, dx \\
&= \beta(n, n+1) = \frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+1)} = \frac{(n-1)!n!}{(2n)!}
\end{align*}

as desired.